# Access layout for SurfaceView (Buttons for SurfaceView)

Tags: android, layout, button, surfaceview

It seems that I’m just not able to understand how SurfaceView and layout should relate. What I’m trying to do is a basic game interface.
My Main Activity is the title screen with a menu and a button that start a new Activity which is the main game screen, and uses an extended SurfaceView to load the level and show up some pictures moving on the screen according to user input.
So far so good, now I’d like to put some special buttons (such as "end game") on the SurfaceView.
I was able to add programmaticaly the button, but I can‘t find out how to associate it to my layout.
So, this is working:

```
public class LevelActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //remove title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    //Prepare Game Class

    LevelView mLevel = new LevelView(this);

    FrameLayout mGame = new FrameLayout(this);
    LinearLayout mGameWidgets = new LinearLayout (this);


    Button EndGameButton = new Button(this);
    mGameWidgets.addView(EndGameButton);       

    mGame.addView(mLevel);
    mGame.addView(mGameWidgets);
    //Prepare moving commands



    EndGameButton.setWidth(300);
    EndGameButton.setText("End Game");



    setContentView(mGame);

}
}
```

However I cannot apply this (or something similar):
    Button EndGameButton = (Button) mLevel.findViewById(R.id.end_game_button);

I’m not sure wether the problem is in the code or in my xml layout file, therefore I’m in trouble figuring out how to solve this.

Thanks, kind regards.